# Flutter - Horizontal RadioButton

Tags: flutter

I want to achieve a horizontal radio buttons layout as shown in the reference image using flutter, is it possible?

[image: Reference]

Comment: Why don't you copy some your code that you have tried yet?

Comment: Please share your code attempt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but it will still help you.

You can seperate each *Container* into widget.

```
 class HorizontalRadioList extends StatefulWidget {
  const HorizontalRadioList({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HorizontalRadioList> createState() => _HorizontalRadioListState();
}

class _HorizontalRadioListState extends State<HorizontalRadioList> {
  int groupValue = 0;

  void changeRadioValue(int? value) {
    groupValue = value!;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(
                color: groupValue == 0 ? Colors.purple : Colors.transparent,
                width: 2,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 24,
                width: 24,
                child: Radio(
                    fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.purple),
                    value: 0,
                    groupValue: groupValue,
                    onChanged: (int? value) {
                      changeRadioValue(value);
                    }),
              ),
              Text('data'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
            color: groupValue == 1 ? Colors.orange : Colors.transparent,
            width: 2,
          ))),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 24,
                width: 24,
                child: Radio(
                    value: 1,
                    fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.orange),
                    groupValue: groupValue,
                    onChanged: (int? value) {
                      changeRadioValue(value);
                    }),
              ),
              Text('data'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
            color: groupValue == 2 ? Colors.green : Colors.transparent,
            width: 2,
          ))),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 24,
                width: 24,
                child: Radio(
                    value: 2,
                    fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                    groupValue: groupValue,
                    onChanged: (int? value) {
                      changeRadioValue(value);
                    }),
              ),
              Text('data'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).